# UIView animations, are they using "Core Animation"

Tags: objective-c, uiview, core-animation

I'm trying to understand a basic point of the various graphics frameworks. Are UIView animations technically a feature of Core Animation or they an entirely different system? Where is the line drawn on differentiating the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CoreAnimation` framework sits lower than `UIKit` so it would probably be safe to assume that the `UIKit` animations are simply built from `CoreAnimation` animations rather than reimplementing their own animation logic. Below is the diagram from an Apple talk (Session 409 - Using the Camera with AV Foundation - 2010) to show how it's placed

```
              +--------------+
              |     UIKit    |
              +--------------+

------------------------------------------------

              +--------------+
              | AVFoundation |
              +--------------+

+-----------+ +--------------+ +---------------+
| CoreAudio | |  CoreMedia   | | CoreAnimation |
+-----------+ +--------------+ +---------------+
```